# Azure CDN endpoint with hosted service on staging and production

Tags: azure, cdn

With an Azure CDN endpoint that is mapped to a hosted service, how do I manage the difference between staging and production?  I want users of my staging site to see CDN pages fetched from my staging deployment, and similarly for the production service.  But since I cannot create an endpoint per deployment, I cannot see how the correct content can be served - they will both be using the same xx123456.vo.msecnd.net address.  (Perhaps it is possible to create CDN endpoints associated with a particular deployment using the REST API, [but the documentation is missing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460786).)

Comment: In response to a support ticket Microsoft has explained the missing documentation as follows: the "REST API for CDN is not available at this moment, but that [it] is under development and will go to market this year".

Comment: And now they have removed the CDN section from the linked document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a support ticket I put into Microsoft, you cannot do this.  The CDN only works with production hosted services.

Comment: The production / staging is a half way solution. Same problem with any external resources like databases (prod vs. test).